# How to split a text file without delimiters

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, split, file-io

I have a homework assignment that involves File IO and 2D arrays. We were given a text file that looks like this:

```
10,10
@,-
oxxxxxxxxo
xoxxxxxxox
xxoxxxxoxx
xxxoxxoxxx
xxxxooxxxx
xxxxooxxxx
xxxoxxoxxx
xxoxxxxoxx
xoxxxxxxox
oxxxxxxxxo
```

I was able to load in the text file properly and the first two lines are not a problem, but I am trying to separate each row into separate individual characters so I can put them into the 2D array. I cannot use regex and have spent hours trying to find an answer. Does anyone have any ideas how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the data supposed to mean? What result are you trying to achieve? What code have you written so far?

Comment: Read each line as a string and a string is an `Enumerable<char>` that you can loop over.  Or just use `ToCharArray()` to get a `char[]` from the string.

Comment: @Charlieface the two 10s at the top are supposed to be the width and height of the 2D array. The program is going to run the Game of Life (not the board game, the one about cells). The '@' is supposed to replace the 'o' representing the cells that are alive, and the '-' instead of the 'x'.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, I don't have room for the code or don't know how.
                `string[] cell = new string[arrayWidth];
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayHeight; i++)
                   {  line = reader.ReadLine();
                    for (int j = 0; j < arrayWidth; j++)
                        {  cell[i] = ____;
                        if (cell[j] == "o")
                            {  cell[j] = isAlive;}
                        else {  cell[j] = isDead; }
                        fileData[i, j] = cell[j];
                        Console.Write(fileData[i, j]); `

Comment: When you have additional information, edit it into your question rather than just mentioning it in comments that may not be read before somebody gives you downvotes. Also, you can see that posting large snippets of code as comments don't work well. When you arrive at a solution, you can post it as an answer to your own question. That will be perfectly acceptable if you choose to. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value = @"10,10
@,-
oxxxxxxxxo
xoxxxxxxox
xxoxxxxoxx
xxxoxxoxxx
xxxxooxxxx
xxxxooxxxx
xxxoxxoxxx
xxoxxxxoxx
xoxxxxxxox
oxxxxxxxxo";

            string[] allLines = value.Split(new string[1] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            string firstLine = allLines[0]; // 10,10
            string secondLine = allLines[1]; // @,-
            string[] rest = Enumerable.Take<string>(allLines, allLines.Length - 2).ToArray<string>();

            // Inconvenient : as we use jagged/multidimensional arrays here, the length must be known in advanceand must be the same in each line we read.
            char[,] valuesAs2DArray = new char[rest.Length,10];

            int i = 0;
            foreach (string s in rest.Skip(2))
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < s.Length;j++)
                {
                    valuesAs2DArray[i,j] = s[j];                    
                }
                i++;
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```